# Comparisons and sorting from point of view of information theory

Tags: algorithms, it.information-theory

Suppose we have list of numbers and make some comparisons. What is known about amount of information which we gain by certain comparisons, by certain sequences of comparisons? Is there algorithm which maximizes obtained information by selecting numbers to compare by results of previous comparisons?

EDIT: numbers are arbitrary integers.

Comment: Related keyword: presortedness. In particular, paper "Encroaching lists as a measure of presortedness".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the numbers are members of a finite set or not. If the set is finite and the source of the numbers satisfy certain conditions (e.g. stationarity and ergodicity), then it is possible to estimate the information content (in the spirit of Shannon) in a predictive way applying comparisons etc. See https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0203/0203436.pdf and references therein.